# Is Mini DisplayPort-to-Mini DisplayPort cable different than Thunderbolt-to-Thunderbolt?

Tags: macos, mac

I currently trying to connect iMac late 09 in target display mode to a MacBook Pro 15" but I’m not getting it detected.

My setup uses Thunderbolt-to-Thunderbolt however [this Apple document says](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204592) I can use only work with Mini DisplayPort-to-Mini DisplayPort. Are those cables really different? Or am I having other problem?

Answer (score 2):

Yes the cables are different.  Thunderbolt cables have a small transceiver chip in the cable head.  MiniDP cables do not.

**Short answer:**
A Mini DisplayPort device MUST be connected with a Mini DisplayPort cable, not a Thunderbolt cable.  You CAN use your '09 iMac in target display mode w/ your 15" MacBook Pro, but you have to connect it with a MiniDP cable.

**Long answer:**
Thunderbolt is a daisy-chain bus that supports multiple devices whereas mini DisplayPort on your iMac is a passive connection that supports only one device. The chips in the Thunderbolt cable manage the connection between Thunderbolt devices.  This is why the cables are so expensive.

By plugging a Thunderbolt cable into the port, you've implied to the computer that there's another Thunderbolt device on the other end of the cable.  The MiniDP signal does get carried by the cable, but the signal is multiplexed in with the Thunderbolt signal, requiring a Thunderbolt device on the other end of the cable to demux it again so it can be passed on to a non-Thunderbolt display further down the chain.  A non-Thunderbolt display will not understand this multiplexed signal.

Comment: Almost got it. DisplayPort also supports daisy chaining though. ;)

Comment: Macs don't though ;-)  Only the DisplayPort 1.2 spec supports that. The DP signal over Thunderbolt is 1.1a.

Comment: [That’s also no longer true.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunderbolt_%28interface%29#Thunderbolt_2), though it still applies in the context of this question. Nevertheless, you should reword your answer to reflect the current state of things.

Comment: I stand corrected. I updated my answer to add that qualifier that *his* iMac only supports 1 device.  Despite that, however, Apple *still* doesn't support that part of the spec according to [this MacWorld article](http://www.macworld.com/article/2083257/what-you-need-to-know-about-thunderbolt-2.html).  The only other search results I get are just people having problems making it work so I assume that MacWorld article is correct.

Answer (score 0):

By "connect in target mode" I assume that you are talking about trying to use one the mentioned machines as external harddrive!

As the iMac late 2009 doesn't have a Thunderbolt-connector you won't have much luck using a Thunderbolt-cable. The iMac only can be used as external machine via FireWire.

Depending on the MacBook PRo that will bring you into trouble as you might not have a firewire-connector. That will mean that you either need a thunderbolt-to-firewire adapter for the MacBook or a third machine that has a thunderbolt- and a firewire-conncetor which you could use as "gateway".

You can plug a thunderbolt-cable into the display-port of the iMac, but it would then only work as display-cable.

Comment: I believe he is referring to target display mode so he can use his iMac as a 2nd monitor for his laptop.  This is not the same as target disk mode, where you can make a 2nd Mac behave as though it were an external hard drive.

Comment: "target mode" normally refers to target disk mode as described in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Target_Disk_Mode as it's supported by all macs. That's why I added the "I assume" ;) For troubleshooting Target DISPLAY mode have a look at https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204592 which clearly states that you can use EITHER a thunderbolt OR a miniDisplayPort-cable.

Comment: If you read a little farther down on that page, it makes it clear that the the '09 and '10 models must use MiniDP cables ;-)  Although pointing me to this article did remind me that the 21" iMacs do not support TDM. Only the 27" models do.

Comment: Oh - Damned. One should always read the complete page :) Thanks for pointing out ;)

Answer (score -1):

My 2009 imac only supports target mode via firewire 800 - It has displayport - same connection as thunderbolt but is displayport only.

Later models may support thunderbolt target mode.

Comment: He's specifically referring to Target Display Mode, not Target Disk mode (as evidenced by the link he posted).  I missed that too, which is why I removed my comment asking him for clarification.